# Salesforce calls from Sesame (relational junction) are timing out

Tags: apex, visualforce, api, wsdl2apex

Just saw an error confirming that SalesForce is timing out Sesame calls:

> ConnectionException Failed to send request to
>   https://xyx.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/30.0/00Di.......
>   connection.getTimeout=1800000  Failed to send request to
>   https://xyz.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/30.0/00Di......
>   com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Failed to send request to
>   https://xyz.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/30.0/00Di0000000hpx1  at
>   com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:120) 
>   at
>   com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection.queryMore(PartnerConnection.java:1311)
>   at
>   com.relationaljunction.rj4salesforce.etl.RJGetUpdated.processQueryResults(RJGetUpdated.java:593)
>   at
>   com.relationaljunction.rj4salesforce.etl.RJGetUpdated.getUpdated(RJGetUpdated.java:335)
>   at
>   com.relationaljunction.rj4salesforce.etl.ETLSfdc.getUpdatedSOQL(ETLSfdc.java:2332)
>   at
>   com.relationaljunction.rj4salesforce.etl.ETLSfdc.main(ETLSfdc.java:904)

A little more information. Requests to SalesForce’s API to get lists of objects are taking a large amounts of time. It is taking a large amount of time.

Please assist.

Comment: Are you using compression for the SOAP response? How many and what type of columns are you bringing back? What does the underlying SOQL query look like and what is does it's query plan look like?